# Echarts rich text icons on bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

I am trying to make my chart have icons.

So I followed the documentation and came up with the following:

```
var weatherIcons = {
    'Sunny': './data/asset/img/weather/sunny_128.png',
    'Cloudy': './data/asset/img/weather/cloudy_128.png',
    'Showers': './data/asset/img/weather/showers_128.png'
};

var seriesLabel = {
    normal: {
        show: true,
        textBorderColor: '#333',
        textBorderWidth: 2
    }
}

option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Wheater Statistics'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['City Alpha', 'City Beta', 'City Gamma']
    },
    toolbox: {
        show: true,
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        name: 'Days',
        data: ['Cloudy', 'Sunny', 'Showers'],

        formatter: function (value) {
            return '{' + value + '| }\n{value|' + value + '}';
        },
        axisLabel: {
            margin: 20,
            rich: {
                value: {
                    lineHeight: 30,
                    align: 'center'
                },
                Sunny: {
                    height: 20,
                    align: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: {
                        image: weatherIcons.Sunny
                    }
                },
                Cloudy: {
                    height: 20,
                    align: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: {
                        image: weatherIcons.Cloudy
                    }
                },
                Showers: {
                    height: 20,
                    align: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: {
                        image: weatherIcons.Showers
                    }
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'City Alpha',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [165, 170, 30],
            
        },
        {
            name: 'City Beta',
            type: 'bar',
            label: seriesLabel,
            data: [150, 105, 110]
        },
        {
            name: 'City Gamma',
            type: 'bar',
            label: seriesLabel,
            data: [220, 82, 63]
        }
    ]
};
```

You can test this out by going to this link: [Link to Echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text) and pasting the code.

How can I get the chart to show the icons?

Comment: It helped my situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **wrong place** of `formatter`'s function

`formatter` should be inside the `axisLabel`

**Example:**

```
xAxis: {
   // ....
   axisLabel: {
      formatter: function (value) {
         return '{' + value + '| }\n{value|' + value + '}';
      },
      // ....
   }
}
```

Comment: this worked! Thank you. 1 question how can i make sure that i get an icon on all of the data sets? (categories)